# Execute a Greasemonkey script on every page, regardless of page-type (like foo.com/image.jpg)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, greasemonkey

Chrome works just fine, and my Greasemonkey script, if copy/pasted into Firefox's Firebug, works just fine on these pages but I can't seem to get it automatically execute.

Download & install the script: http://sente.cc/js/testing_greasemonkey.user.js

and then go to https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK8ve.jpg (observe simple alert) and https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0tbI.jpg (observe no alert)

*the script:*

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Testing Greasemonkey
// @namespace     stuartpowers
// @description   Testing Greasemonkey
// @author        Stuart Powers
// @homepage      http://sente.cc/
// @include       http://i.imgur.com/*
// @include       http://imgur.com/*
// ==/UserScript==


// load https://i.stack.imgur.com/MK8ve.jpg (works)
// load https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0tbI.jpg (doesn't work)

(function () {
    alert("worked");
})()
```

Comment: I think not. Although Fx DOES create a pseudo html page for plugins like PDF

Comment: Perhaps you simply need to allow Greasemonkey to operate on files? [link](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Include_and_exclude_rules#Extra_schemes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Greasemonkey requires an explicit DOM to fire and act upon.  It cannot run on Chrome-generated<sup>1</sup> pseudo-DOM<sup>2</sup>.

If you want to act on these kind of "pages", you'll have to write a Firefox extension (add-on).  (Note that userscripts in Google-Chrome are converted into mini extensions.)

Here are some add-on resources, I've found helpful:

- [Mozilla extensions home page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions)
- [Add-on Builder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/tools/builder)
- [10 Things They Never Tell You In Firefox Extension School](http://www.sitepoint.com/ten-tips-firefox-extensions/)
- [Developing Firefox Extensions – Paper](http://www.disenchant.ch/blog/developing-firefox-extensions-paper/96)

---

<sup>1</sup> Here, "Chrome" refers to the privileged DOM that makes up the Firefox's UI.
<sup>2</sup> With select exceptions.